# Page links style messing up with navigation menu links style. Possible to use different link styles?

Tags: html, css

I've noticed that the CSS code related to my regular page links had an impact on the navigation items of my webpage navigation menu.
How can I avoid that and keep the navigation menu links styled as they initially were? See http://jsfiddle.net/8MwX7/

Many thanks

**Page links:**

```
a:link {
    border-bottom: none;
    color: #2d7ddf;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #2d7ddf;
    background: none;
}
a:visited {
    background: none;
}
a:active {
    background: none;
}
```

**Navigation menu:**

```
nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
    margin-right: -4px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    }
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
nav a {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;

}
nav a:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35)
}
.activeNav {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35)
}
nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;

    background: none;
    padding-top: 5px
}
nav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
nav ul li ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
    padding: 10px
}
nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    background: rgba(20,150,220,0.5);
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
.hover a {
    display: block;
}
.hover span {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    background: rgba(20,150,220,0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0 0 -57px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: How were they styled, and what is wrong now? Please provide more details

Comment: @imbondbaby that you can easily see if you remove the common css for `<a>` given separately in question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark the styles of your menu with `!important` to prevent it from being overridden.

```
nav a {
 /*other css rules*/
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1) !important ; 
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/8MwX7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that using the !important keyword in CSS is generally considered bad practice.

[What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

http://james.padolsey.com/usability/dont-use-important/

The reason your styles are not working correctly because

```
    a:link, a:hover, a:active, a:visited
```

are considered more specific than

```
nav a
```

If you would like to correct this without using the important tag then modify 'nav a' to the following:

```
nav a:link, nav a:hover, nav a:active, nav a:visited {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

The code above makes the following css:

```
nav a:link, nav a:hover, nav a:active, nav a:visited
```

more specific than

```
a:link, a:hover, a:active, a:visited
```

Here is a link to an updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8MwX7/2/